# Existe alguma biblioteca em python para encontrar uma palavra válida no dicionário em português?

Tags: python-3.x, dicionário, analise-de-texto

Essa é a fonte que estou utilizano https://github.com/pythonprobr/palavras

```py
    import base64
    import requests

    master = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pythonprobr/palavras/master/palavras.txt"
    req = requests.get(master)
    req = req.text
    dicionario_palavras_portugues = req.split('\n')
 
    palavra = input("Digite uma palavra: ").lower()

    for idx, value in enumerate(dicionario_palavras_portugues):

    if palavra == value:
        print(f"Verdadeiro : indice ${idx}")
        print(f"Palavra: ${dicionario_palavras_portugues[idx]")
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Estou usando esse método que utiliza um corretor ortográfico como palavras válidas. Isso inclui nomes próprios. Gostaria de me limitar ao que está em dicionários de português.

Comment: Recomendação de produtos não é bem o perfil do site, mas além da resposta dada ainda tem o campo de comentários (este tipo de coisa é melhor pelo chat da rede, com mais alguns pontos você já tem acesso, segue link: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910) Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algo que uso em diferentes projetos e "linguagens" é o [Hunspell](http://hunspell.github.io/) (usado também  pelo LibreOffice, OpenOffice.org, Mozilla Firefox 3 & Thunderbird, Google Chrome e também por sistemas/programas proprietários.), que suportará os arquivos `.dic`/`.aff`.

Para Python existe uma lib (via pip) que possibilitará checar as palavras usando o *motor Hunspell*: https://pypi.org/project/cyhunspell/

Para instalar via pip use:

```
pip install cyhunspell
```

> **Nota:** A vantagem dessa biblioteca comparada a outras é que não precisa ter instalado o libhunspell-dev e nem o python-dev

Depois baixe o arquivo `.dic` e o `.aff` do idioma desejado, existem diversos repositórios de distros (linux) ou programas offices que disponibilizam esses arquivos mais atualizados (já que os idiomas sempre podem sofrer variações ou que simplesmente os próprios dicionários precisem de correções), no caso um que me recordo no momento (creio estar atualizado) é o:

- https://github.com/titoBouzout/Dictionaries

Baixe os arquivos (se for para o português do Brasil):

```
Portuguese (Brazilian).aff
Portuguese (Brazilian).dic
```

Ou então:

```
Portuguese (European).aff
Portuguese (European).dic
```

E salve-os em uma pasta que o seu script possa localizar (no meu caso criei uma pasta chamada "dicionários")

Depois no seu script link o arquivo assim:

```
from hunspell import Hunspell

h = Hunspell('Portuguese (Brazilian)', hunspell_data_dir=r'C:\Users\inphinit\dicionarios')
```

Note que o primeiro parâmetro recebeu o valor correspondente ao nome do arquivo sem a extensão, dessa forma você poderá alternar entre diferentes dicionários (se houver necessidade).

Depois use o método `hunspell.Hunspell.spell(<palavra>)` assim:

```
from hunspell import Hunspell

h = Hunspell('Portuguese (Brazilian)', hunspell_data_dir=r'C:\Users\inphinit\dicionarios')

print(h.spell('Gato'))     # True
print(h.spell('Cachorro')) # True
print(h.spell('Foobar'))   # False
```

Se por acaso retornar `False` você poderá verificar se existem sugestões com `hunspell.Hunspell.suggest(<palavra>)`, exemplo:

```
from hunspell import Hunspell

h = Hunspell('Portuguese (Brazilian)', hunspell_data_dir=r'C:\Users\inphinit\dicionarios')

palavra = 'sapatus'; # palavra errada

if h.spell(palavra):
    print('Correto')
else:
    print('Sugestões', h.suggest(palavra))
```